# !java.util.LinkedHashMap appearing in file while using YAML Beans Writer

Tags: java, yaml, yamlbeans

I am reading a yaml file and I am writing it simply to a path (e.g. I am reading a test.yml file and writing it to tester.yml). I can now read and write the file but the actual problem is that I am getting **"!java.util.LinkedHashMap"** in my out put file. I am using YAML BEANS to read and write to the file.

MY Output:
    !java.util.LinkedHashMap
    Error: !java.util.LinkedHashMap
       type: object
       properties: !java.util.LinkedHashMap
          errorMessage: !java.util.LinkedHashMap
             type: string
             description: Message describing the error (Do not give too much information, to avoid security
                reach)
          errorLevel: !java.util.LinkedHashMap
             type: string
             description: Criticity level of error
             default: info
             enum: 
             - info
             - warning
             - error
             - critical
          errorType: !java.util.LinkedHashMap
             type: string
             description: Type of error
             enum: 
             - functional
             - technical
          documentationUrl: !java.util.LinkedHashMap
             type: string
             description: Url of the documenation associated to the error
          tips: !java.util.LinkedHashMap
             type: string
             description: Tips/help for adressing the error
             required: 
             - errorMessage
             - errorCode

MY code

```
    Reader targetReader = new InputStreamReader(uploadedFile);
YamlReader yamlReader=new YamlReader(targetReader);
        YamlWriter yamlWriter= new YamlWriter(new FileWriter("filename"));
        Object object = yamlReader.read();
        System.out.println(object);
        yamlWriter.write(object);
        yamlWriter.close();
```

MY Input
    Error:
        type: object
        properties:
          errorMessage:
            type: string
            description: >-
              Message describing the error (Do not give too much information, to
              avoid security reach)
          errorLevel:
            type: string
            description: Criticity level of error
            default: info
            enum:
              - info
              - warning
              - error
              - critical
          errorType:
            type: string
            description: Type of error
            enum:
              - functional
              - technical
          documentationUrl:
            type: string
            description: Url of the documenation associated to the error
          tips:
            type: string
            description: Tips/help for adressing the error
            required:
              - errorMessage
              - errorCode

Any help and suggestions are welcome thanks in advance.....
**Solution for this one is**

```
yamlWriter.getConfig().writeConfig.setWriteClassname(YamlConfig.WriteClassName.NEVER);
        yamlWriter.getConfig().writeConfig.setWriteRootTags(false);
```

Comment: Please provide sample source code and yaml file so that someone can reproduce the issue

Comment: You probably need to configure this library to assume this type. In the case of Chronicle Wire, I don't include the type if it's a LinkedHashMap.